# jQuery: Append doesn't work with leading spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, whitespace

If I use jQuery's .append() with a string that has leading spaces, it skips the spaces.

Example: `$("#div").append("    test");` appends `test` without the four spaces that are in front of it.

How would I allow the appending of leading spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you expecting to see the white space on the page? if so, you need to use `&nbsp;`s or non-breaking spaces.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/W6RMA/

Comment: I just thought of that right after this was posted, and welcome to `stackoverflow`!